# What is the subject of the following sentence?

Tags: sentence, subjects

> Food allergies are adverse reactions to an otherwise harmless food or food component that involves an abnormal response of the body's immune system to specific protein(s) in foods.

This is a beginning sentence of a paper on food allergies. I was wondering what the subject of the verb *involves* and have asked opinions from three English language experts who also have scientific knowledge, but their opinions vary. Their answers were as follows:

Person 1: The subject is *food allergies* and the verb should be *involve*.

Person 2: The subject is *abnormal response* and the verb should be *involve*.

Person 3: The subject is *food or food component*, so this sentence is correct. He also pointed out that the paper is written in British English (I showed him the following sentences and he got some clues from there) so here *involves* means *evokes* or *causes*.

Which of these opinions is the correct one?

Comment: @Matt: I'm not sure why the title of this question was edited from "what is the subject" to "how can I determine the subject", because the OP seems to be asking (and others seem to be answering) the former, not the latter. However, I'm reluctant to edit it back in case there was a specific reason I'm not aware of...?

Comment: I don't know much British English, but I've never heard "involve" used to mean "evoke" or "cause," and OED doesn't give that definition either. Furthermore, the [original document](http://www.fao.org/docrep/007/y0820e/y0820e04.htm) from the FAO shows that the very next sentence is: "True food allergies may involve several types of immunological responses (Sampson and Burks, 1996)."

Comment: @aaamos That's true. I think I changed it because asking "what is the subject of this sentence" comes across to me as too localised, whereas the question "how do I determine the subject" is something that applies to everyone. Feel free to change it back.

Comment: Thanks, @MattЭллен, I took the liberty of changing it back and removed the invitation to give "opinions" while I was at it.

Answer (score 7):

I think your Person 2 is supposed to say that the subject of the verb "involve" is "*adverse reactions*." I agree with the example that tchrist says, although the "Person 2" example wouldn't make sense. I think you should edit your question title to ask for the subject of the verb, because the subject of the sentence is obviously "food allergies."

And scientifically, that would make the most sense to me. It's not usually the food that's the cause of the problem, but the body's improper immune response to it. The body is normally able to discriminate between food (which should have no immune response) and bacteria, fungi, and other bad things (which should be attacked by your mucosal immune system). But you were asking about grammar, not biology...

I put this in a comment but also want to add it here. The next sentence from the [original FAO report](http://www.fao.org/docrep/007/y0820e/y0820e04.htm) says: "*True food allergies may involve several types of immunological responses*." I think that makes it unlikely that the scientists intended to use the definition in the third example.

Answer (score 6):

I vote for number two.  I think the sentence is fundamentally trying to say:

> Allergies are reactions  that involves a response.

Which if my reading is correct, means that *involves* needs to be *involve*.

Comment: That reading totally discards **something** (call it **X**) which I think is quite important to the sentence. **X** = *"to an otherwise harmless food or food component"*. Try putting it back in, as *"Food allergies are adverse reactions to **X**, that involve an abnormal response to something within **X***. That makes more sense to me. It's still crap writing though.

Comment: @Fumble: even when you put **X** back in, though, the predicate **involve(s)** should _still_ agree with the subject **allergies**, shouldn't it?  (**X** is a prepositional phrase that should be able to be inserted or removed without changing the tense of the verb.)

Comment: @J.R.: Surely. I didn't mean the *verb tense* was wrong - I just meant the basic structure is *"Allergies are **X's** that **involve Y's**"*. However I look at it, the subject of that is *allergies* (not *an abnormal response*, which just happens to be part of the convoluted phrase I just represented as ***X***). On the basis of grammar alone, John Lawler is prepared to accept that *"involves"* could be valid - but semantically and stylistically, I think not. Terrible writing though it is, the only credible subject is *"Allergies"*.

Comment: ...although having said that, I realise it's equally valid (and semantically equivalent) to say the subject is *"reactions"*, since the first three words in tchrist's recasting actually tell us that *those two nouns represent the same thing[s]*. So they both match OP's interpretation #1, not #2 which tchrist has plumped for here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My answer is predicated on the assumption that the *“that”* is referring back to *“reactions”*, because that’s what makes the most sense semantically to me. That’s why it needs a plural verb *“involve”*. John’s answer posits that the sentence is *a priori* grammatical and so searches for a singular subject to match *“involves”* no matter whether it’s sensible or not, somewhat as one does in decoding Latin. His chosen subject of *“food component”* does not make sense to me, because it’s reactions that involve responses, not food components.

Comment: @tchrist: I seem to agree with everything you say, apart from your conclusion that OP's #2 is therefore the "correct" interpretation. It seems clear-cut to me that #1 is the only "credible" interpretation, though I do like the clarity of how you explain John's answer as stemming from an *a priori* acceptance of the sentence's structural validity (even though, like you, I find that position eventually collapses at the semantic level).

Comment: Aren't you both debating two separate things? The OP's question and examples are contradictory and thus really, really, confusing. My understanding is that the OP is asking for the subject of the *verb*, not of the sentence (despite the title). And #2 (as written) is completely wrong. It should say that the subject of the verb is *adverse reactions*. In terms of the science, it also has to be "adverse reactions" ... Someone please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @jello The subject of *involves* is *that*, the relative pronoun serving as the subject of its subordinate clause. The open question is what its antecedent is intended to be.

Answer (score 4):

The question asks for the subject of the sentence

> ***Food allergies are** adverse reactions to an otherwise harmless food or food component that involves an abnormal response of the body's immune system to specific protein(s) in foods*

The subject of **this** sentence is *Food allergies*, which is a plural noun phrase, and agrees with the verb *are*, which is also plural.

However, the rest of the question appears to refer to the relative clause

> ***that involves** an abnormal response of the body's immune system to specific protein(s) in foods*

which follows and modifies the noun *component*. This is **not** the main clause, and is **not** a sentence. However, it is a clause and it has a subject.

The subject is *that*; as a relative pronoun, it can be singular or plural, depending on its antecedent. In this case, the antecedent of *that* is *component*, which is singular, and agrees with the singular verb *involves*.

You have to distinguish clauses from one another before you can talk about sentences usefully.

Comment: You seem to be happy to accept *that involves* as referencing *an otherwise harmless food or food component*. I can see that grammatically that's the only plausible option, but semantically I can't make sense of it. What could it possibly *mean* to speak of a "harmless food" involving an "abnormal reaction"? I'm sure the writer actually meant to be referencing **food allergies**, since obviously they are indeed things which **involve** "an abnormal response which blah blah". In short, OP's citation seems clumsy, verbose, and ungrammatical to me.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't; almost all the questions and example sentences posted here are clumsy, verbose, and ungrammatical. Nothing new there. But they asked about the grammar.

Comment: Fair enough. Having looked at the other answers, and reconsidered the question itself, I think it's just an example of bad writing. It's not worth picking out one "interpretation" over another - the whole sentence is so tortuous it's hard to nail down exactly what the writer intended. But it's nothing anywhere near as complex or erudite as the phrasing implies, I think.

Comment: I appreciate your knowledge, and your answers are always very erudite. Still, you frequently come through as if you were delivering a lecture at university. Is it really so difficult to avoid being condescending in your replies? Most people writing here are doing their best, and do not need to be "scolded" as you seem to do for example in the last sentence of your above answer, a needless addendum in my opinion.

Comment: So you’re saying that you think “food component involves” is more semantically sensible than “reactions involve”?  Really?

Comment: "that involves" is establishing a restrictive condtion on "adverse reactions (to an otherwise harmless food or food component)" and as such should match the reactions which is plural.

Comment: True. But the subject _that_ modifies, and thus is coreferential with, the singular noun _component._ So the subject is singular, and that grammatical fact determines grammatical verb agreement, no matter whether something else that it may imply might be plural, or not. Grammar and meaning are **not** the same.

Answer (score 3):

The subject is *reactions*. Should read: “… that involve …”. It is the reactions that involve the abnormal responses.

Answer (score 1):

[1] Food allergies are adverse reactions to an otherwise harmless food or food component that involves an abnormal response of the body's immune system to specific protein(s) in foods.

remove all adjectives and adverbs:

[2] Allergies are reactions to a food or component that involves a response.

"to a food or component" is a preposition that modifies "reactions", so remove it.

[3] Allergies are reactions that involves a response.

What is the subject of "involves a response"? ---> "that"
"That" is a relative pronoun.
The antecedent is "reactions".

This creates the clause "reactions involves and response" which has incorrect subject/verb agreement.

"That involves a response" is a clause, so remove it.

final sentence -->  "Allergies are reactions".

Answer (score 0):

- The given conjugation ("involves") requires a singular subject.
- The construction being used here is "<actor> that <action being performed>".

Given these two points, person 3 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If "involves" in British English means "evokes or causes", then the sentence is grammatically and biologically correct.  If this is a paper intended for a broad audience (i.e., a medical journal) the language should be "more standard" to avoid ambiguity. I think if "evokes" had been used it would not be ambiguous.